# link won't work if its wrapping an i tag

Tags: html

Why is my link not working if it has an  element as a child? Is there a solution to this? I've found this one: [When I wrap contents in an <a> tag, the link doesn't work in IE, help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496525/when-i-wrap-contents-in-an-a-tag-the-link-doesnt-work-in-ie-help)
and it suggests using a div instead of an anchor tag but I want to stick with default browser functionality and don't want to write a script for this.

```
<td class="pointer">
            <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/user/' . $user->user_id) }}"><i class="icons foundicon-unlock"></i></a>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code posted creates an `a` element with an `i` element as content, the latter having no content, so we can say it’s an empty link. Whether it works is a matter of definition. Google will follow it, and users might be able to focus on it and follow it by hitting Enter. But there won’t be anything clickable, so people generally won’t see any link. This does not depend on the inner `i` element. You get the same result by using an `a` element with empty content.

But the class names used suggest that you expect some style sheet to format the empty link so that it looks like a link, presumably using a background image. And presumably that code relies on specific expectations on the markup, and your use of `i` may fail to meet them.

So consult the documentation of the CSS (or JavaScript?) code you are using. If problems remain, please post all the relevant code and identify where you found the code.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work on IE or all the browsers because it works for me

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WNpLt/)

If you want you can take out `<i>` tags out of `<a>` element

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/WNpLt/1/)

HTML

```
<i><a href="www.google.com">Google</a></i> <!--Tested on IE 7,8,9 and obviously on firefox-->
```

I doubt your `href` attribute, just be sure what you get as a source, and btw you've no text between you `<a>` tags, assume that you are using some image